# Creating a sub-folder in a SharePoint with Client.dll in C#

Tags: client-object-model, folder, c-sharp

I am trying to create a list of all the folders that exist within the root folder. From there I want to implement the creation of a folder if the folder does not already exist.

Is there a way to create a folder on the root path if the folder does not exist?

**Current Code**

```
public void ListFolders_CreateIfNone(string listTitle, string folderName)
    {
        using (var clientContext = OpenConnectionToSharePoint())
        {
            var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);


            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var folderCollection = list.RootFolder.Folders;

            foreach (var folder in folderCollection)
            {
                if (folder.Name == folderName)
                {
                    clientContext.Load(folder.Files);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    var i = folderCollection.Add(folder.Name);
                    i.Update();
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**
#

```
 public void ListFolders_CreateIfNone(string listTitle, string folderName)
    {
        using (var clientContext = OpenConnectionToSharePoint())
        {
            var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
            list.EnableFolderCreation = true;

            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
            clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var folderCollection = list.RootFolder.Folders;

            foreach (var folder in folderCollection)
            {

                if (folder.Name == folderName)
                {
                    clientContext.Load(folder.Files);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation
                    {
                        UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder,
                        LeafName = folderName
                    };

                    var newItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                    newItem["Title"] = folderName;
                    newItem.Update();
                    clientContext.Credentials = NetworkCredential();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    break;
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

This is the method that I created to check to see if a folder already existed ... if there was no folder I would then create the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `.RootFolder`, then I will go with NO. That folder should get created when the library was created. If you mean any other folder, then your code should work:

```
var i = folderCollection.Add(folder.Name);  // is this the path to folder? the server relative url?
i.Update();

//try rather
clientContext.Load(i)
clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

If you are getting any errors, post them so we can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ctx.GetListByTitle("MyList);
list.EnableFolderCreation = true;
list.RootFolder.EnsureFolder("ExisingFolder1").EnsureFolder("NewSubFolderToFolder1");
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```